# Is it possible for the client to specify it's type to the websocket server?

Tags: node.js, websocket

I'm new to Node.js and am building a simple websocket server to do simple communication between my android phone and a my computer. My design specification is that my Android should continuously send data to my computer and the computer should occasionally send something back. Let's suppose that I want to scale this up , have two computers and two androids (each of these have designated roles in the infrastructure I have in mind).

So there's Computer1, Computer2, Android1, Android2. All of them are connected to my websocket server

Suppose I'm Android1 and I want to communicate only to Computer1 at some point in time, and then later I want to communicate to Computer2, and later to Android2. How do I (as Android1) tell the server who I want to communicate to at a given moment in time, and what would the code/logic look like on the server-side to direct the flow of traffic?

Comment: https://html5demos.com/web-socket/

Answer (score 0):

This functionality needs to be added at the application level. Websockets is just a low level protocol for sending data between a client and a server. Any additional logic needs to be added inside your app, depending on your architecture. 
You need to enrich the packages sent between your clients/server with additional info (like client type, client ID, IP address etc) to allow some degree of extensibility. 
Some additional things to think about to allow your app to scale:

- add a persistance layer:  save the state of your network in a database, which nodes are online, which client can connect to which server etc
- create a master-worker architecture for your servers: have a single master as a primary server that sends back info to the clients as to which worker they should connect to (assuming that Computer1, Computer2 are your workers)